# Prove that there always exists a fair driving schedule

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

> Some people agree to carpool, but they want to make sure that any
>   carpool arrangement is fair and doesn't overload any single person
>   with too much driving. Some scheme is required because none of them
>   goes to work every day, and so the subset of them in the car varies
>   from day to day.
>
> Let the people be labeled in a set $S = \{p_1,...,p_k\}$. We say that
>   the *total driving obligation* of $p_j$ over a set of days is the
>   expected number of times that $p_j$ would have driven, had a driver
>   been chosen uniformly at random from among the people going to work
>   each day. That is, suppose the carpool plan lasts for $d$ days, and on
>   the $i^{th}$ day a subset $S_i \subseteq S$ of the people go to work.
>   Then the total driving obligation $\delta_j$ for $p_j$ can be written
>   as $\delta_j = \sum_{i:p_j\in S_i} \frac{1}{|S_i|}$. Ideally, we'd
>   like to require that $p_j$ drives at most $\delta_j$ times, but
>   $\delta_j$ may not be an integer.
>
> A *driving schedule* is a choice of a driver for each day$-$a sequence
>   $p_{i_1}, p_{i_2},...,p_{i_d}$ with $p_{i_t}\in S_t-$and that a *fair
>   driving schedule* is one in which $p_j$ is chosen as a driver on at
>   most $\lceil \delta_j \rceil$ days.
>
> 1. Prove that for any sequence of sets $S_1,...,S_d$, there exists a fair driving schedule.

I'm finding this question very difficult to answer. My intuition tells me that there should always be a fair driving schedule, but I don't know how to prove that. I was thinking that we could do things inductively, but the problem breaks down after the base case. For example, consider the base case being $S_1$. Then there always exists a fair driving schedule because every driver $\in S_1$ can only drive at most once. After the base case, if we have just $S_1$ and $S_2$, we run into trouble because $S_1$ and $S_2$ can be completely different, very similar, or mixed. How can we show that there is always a fair driving schedule for just two lists? Generally, how can we extend this to $d$ lists?

Answer (score 1):

There should be always a fair driving schedule since you can model this problem as a [flow network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network). The source is connected with all persons and the capacity of an edge from the source to a person $p_j$ is $\lceil\delta_j\rceil$. The next step is to connect every person with each of his working days. The capacity of each of this edges is $1$. The last step is to connect each day with the sink with capacity $1$.

Applying the [max-flow min-cut theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) to our flow network, we can see that the maximal flow of our network is equal to the number of days, since the minimal cut splits our network into the sink and all other nodes.

Explanation: Without loss of generality, we can assume that each person works at least one day and there are no days without workers. Therefore we exclude all cuts running through an edge which connects a person with a day. The cut which splits our network in source and all other nodes is not minimal since
$$\sum_j\lceil\delta_j\rceil\ge\sum_j\delta_j= \text{number of days}.$$ The mixed cuts are excluded with the combination of the abovementioned arguments.

In conclusion, the maximal flow in our network can be retranslated to our original problem in the following way: If the flow from the node corresponding to person $p$ to the node corresponding to day $t$ is $1$, than $p$ is the driver on $t$.

Note that there are algorithms to determine the maximal flow like the [Ford-Fulkerson-Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm).

Comment: The idea here is solid, but there are two problems: showing that is a minimal cut (it is, but I don't think it's obvious), and showing the sum you mention is at least **number of days**.  The latter is the crux of the problem IMO, and should be explained.

Comment: I edited my post to clearify your points.